# How to access internal servers from https web-server

Tags: rest, web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have the following architecture: network of 2 virtual machines each contains a web-server and has an internal addresses assigned to it (*internal.add1*, *internal.add2*), one external ip address and domain pointing to the external ip (*domain.com*). I also have a ssl certificate issued to *domain.com*. The web-servers linked to ports 3000 and 4000 of the external ip and use the ssl certificate. I want to access the *web-server1* from the *web-sever2*. I can't use external ip because I got invalid common name error. I also can't use domain name because I got connection timeout. What else can I do? Any hints would be highly appreciated.